# ipmitool: how to deal with frozen SOL session

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I use `ipmitool` SOL session to get console logs from remote server. Initially session is responsive. If I hit enter, I can see login message to remote server like below.

```
[SOL Session operational.  Use ~? for help]                                                                                                                               

<hostname> login:
```

But if I don't hit enter after activating session and try to press enter or any key, it does not do anything. I can see only this line:

```
[SOL Session operational.  Use ~? for help]
```

I am not sure if the session becomes frozen or not. I can see help after pressing ~? but it is not helpful to resolve the issue. I don't see that login message again.

I create SOL sessions by using this command:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -U <ipmi-username> -P <ipmi-password> -H <ipmi-ip> sol activate
```

Is there way to generate some logs on this session without shutting off remote server ? And what are the ways to deal with frozen sol sessions ?

Comment: I don't think it is frozen. The terminal displays characters only when it receives a text from the client. Since login screen is not sending any data, it appears to be frozen.

Answer (score 3):

`ipmitool sol deactivate` is supposed to solve this.
But from your question it looks like you have some problems with serial console on the host.